# No alias for debug.keystore android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have am having an issue in Unity version 5.3.1f1, When I try to build a debug version of my app, using the `debug.keystore` in my `.android` folder, Unity finds the keystore, but doesn't give the option to choose an alias other than the unsigned one. I tried deleting and making a new `debug.keystore` assigning a new alias, but it doesn't appear. What should I do?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're entering the right password? Unity only shows the key-aliases in the keystore if you enter the right password for the keystore.

Comment: ...and this is just for sanity sake, hit the return key (enter) after you type in your keystore password.

Comment: I am entering the right password, but still no alias. any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, that's definitely weird. Are you absolutely sure that the keystore does indeed contain an alias?

Comment: Also, regarding your second part of the question, what do you mean by "it doesn't appear"? Do you mean you cannot see the alias even after you go through the process with the new keystore (i.e. selecting, typing password)

Answer (score 0):

If your alias name has space like (my game) then use like this ("my game"). This will work for sure.